# Changing the notification-text on Facebook app requests

Tags: facebook, facebook-app-requests

I've noticed that some Facebook apps, like BranchOut, have customized notifications messages. When an app request is sent and appears in the top left notification center the text on the notification is something they seem to control on their own, instead of the default "Name sent you a request".

From what I find the the documentation this isn't possible. Custom messages are only shown for users already using the app, otherwise you get Facebooks default invite message.

Does anyone know how they are doing this? Do they simply have a deal with Facebook, or are they sending something other than an App Request?

Comment: check this links

  [1]: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6297853/facebook-requests-dialog-not-showing-message-to-recepient
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286817/how-to-send-facebook-apprequests-notifications-with-custom-message-parameter?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just in case someone else finds this question, it appears you can no longer control this message. There are some stuff floating around on other questions but none of them work anymore.

According to the docs, only whitelisted apps are allowed to edit the app request message that shows in the notification itself.

Answer (score 3):

You can send custom notifications with the Notifications API:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/notifications/

These can only be sent to users who already have the app installed.
If you wish to invite someone to the app then you must use apprequest which doesn't allow you to customise the message.